# running Python commands on Atom

Tags: python-3.x, package, atom-editor

So I'm a new intern at a company and they gave me practically a blank computer. I needed to install some programs from their Git to run python and the only available python editors are Idle and Atom. I personally prefer atom, so I installed with the package "script" that should run python scripts. However I can't run python 3.4 and I get this error 
" 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
Which I get since on cmd typing 'python' does not launch the python only typing 'py'. Since I am an intern I have no control over the Environmental variables so I can't change py command to python. How can I change atom script package to use "py" command instead of "python".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by going inscript 3.17.3 code:
script --> lib --> grammars --> python.coffee
In there I changed "command: 'python'" to "command: 'py'" for lines 3 and 7.
This should work for whatever command your windows batch uses to run python.